# Modificar variable desde el argumento de una funcion (conflicto en las importaciones)

Tags: python, programación-funcional, python-import

lo siguiente es código simplificado para mejor comprensión:
hay dos módulos,
el primero:

```
from modulo2 import f1

f=[f1+4,f1+2]

def primero():
    print(f[0])

def segundo():
    print(f[1])
```

el segundo:

```
from  modulo1 import primero,segundo

f1=0    
def funcion_principal(f1):
    primero()
    segundo()    

funcion_principal(5)
funcion_principal(10)
#
#etc
```

es un caso de importación cruzada, y lo que quiero es que al ejecutar `función_principal(f1)`
se modifique  la variable `f1` en el primer modulo de acuerdo al argumento dado.

lo he intentado  de muchas formas sin éxito, siempre recibo un `error` de conflicto en la importación.
gracias por su posible ayuda.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'primero'
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que tal vez estas asumiendo que `from modulo2 import f1` solo obtiene la definición de esta variable del módulo, cosa que es cierta, pero además, para hacerlo, python necesita evaluar también los `imports`, con lo cual volvemos a evaluar nuevamente `modulo1` y luego nuevamente `modulo2` y así. Lo que deberías evitar es el `import` a nivel de módulo y colocarlo a nivel de `función` dónde se realizará cuando realmente se lo necesite, por ejemplo, podrías hacer esto en `modulo2`:

```
def funcion_principal(f1):
    from modulo1 import primero
    from modulo1 import segundo
    primero()
    segundo()
```